# Timeout request on page for redirect is unable to route to another angular view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http

So I found this jquery plugin http://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/ a where an automatic redirected occurs after x amount of seconds has passed. I wanted to incorporate this into one of views in angular however, I'm unable to use the ng route  with jquery function. The programs runs but times out because jquery doesn't recognize "#" routing. If I put the original link of the view (main.html),this takes me to the page,but exits out of application.I also tried setting an iframe since I just want the pop up but I get an http error request

Session Expiration Warning

You've been inactive for a while. Click "Continue" to extend your session.

Your session will expire in 120 seconds.

Continue

```
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="mdlLoggedOut" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">You have been automatically signed out</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Your session has expired.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        var
            session = {
                //Logout Settings
                inactiveTimeout: 10000,     //(ms) The time until we display a warning message
                warningTimeout: 10000,      //(ms) The time until we log them out
                minWarning: 5000,           //(ms) If they come back to page (on mobile), The minumum amount, before we just log them out
                warningStart: null,         //Date time the warning was started
                warningTimer: null,         //Timer running every second to countdown to logout
                logout: function () {       //Logout function once warningTimeout has expired
                    //window.location = settings.autologout.logouturl;

                    $(location).attr('href', 'main.html')
                },

                //Keepalive Settings
                keepaliveTimer: null,
                keepaliveUrl: "",
                keepaliveInterval: 5000,     //(ms) the interval to call said url
                keepAlive: function () {
                    $.ajax({ url: session.keepaliveUrl });
                }
            }
        ;


        $(document).on("idle.idleTimer", function (event, elem, obj) {
            //Get time when user was last active
            var
                diff = (+new Date()) - obj.lastActive - obj.timeout,
                warning = (+new Date()) - diff
            ;

            //On mobile js is paused, so see if this was triggered while we were sleeping
            if (diff >= session.warningTimeout || warning <= session.minWarning) {
                window.location.replace("#");
            } else {
                //Show dialog, and note the time
                $('#sessionSecondsRemaining').html(Math.round((session.warningTimeout - diff) / 1000));
                $("#timeout").modal("show");
                session.warningStart = (+new Date()) - diff;

                //Update counter downer every second
                session.warningTimer = setInterval(function () {
                    var remaining = Math.round((session.warningTimeout / 1000) - (((+new Date()) - session.warningStart) / 1000));
                    if (remaining >= 0) {
                        $('#sessionSecondsRemaining').html(remaining);
                    } else {
                        session.logout();
                    }
                }, 1000)
            }
        });

        // create a timer to keep server session alive, independent of idle timer
        session.keepaliveTimer = setInterval(function () {
            session.keepAlive();
        }, session.keepaliveInterval);

        //User clicked ok to extend session
        $("#extendSession").click(function () {
            clearTimeout(session.warningTimer);
        });
        //User clicked logout
        $("#logoutSession").click(function () {
            session.logout();
        });

        //Set up the timer, if inactive for 10 seconds log them out
        $(document).idleTimer(session.inactiveTimeout);
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing jquery with angular is not a good idea. If you want to achieve url redirection after certain time period you can achieve this with approach below

```
var timeoutperiod;
var redirect = function (url){
   $window.location.href = url;
 };

if (timeoutperiod) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutperiod);
    }
timeoutperiod = setTimeout(redirect('url'), 5000);
```

Please make sure to inject $window into your controller.

Comment: Ok. and the actual url is defined in timeoutperiod = setTimeout(redirect('url'), 5000); correct?